# GAE Filter AdminMessage Recipients

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am using the PHP runtime and when I send an admin email (which uses the Admin Emails quota) using the code below it works and I receive the email. However it sends the message to all users with admin permissions (as listed under Permissions in the GAE Admin Console) which as well as me includes two (non-user) service accounts (e.g. 12345678@project.gserviceaccount.com & myappid@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) which bounce.

```
<?
require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/AdminMessage.php';
use \google\appengine\api\mail\AdminMessage;

$message = new AdminMessage(array("sender"=> "noreply@myappid.appspotmail.com"));
$message->setSubject("Admin Mail Test");
$message->setHtmlBody("Hello");
$message->send();

?>
```

Is there a way to exclude those accounts whilst still using AdminMessage?

Comment: Having a look at the source -

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/c10d3bdc6af30cb71cfb8a5a8551450e8ccce29c/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/AdminMessage.php

Which extends -

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/c10d3bdc6af30cb71cfb8a5a8551450e8ccce29c/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/BaseMessage.php

And it looks like the setters for the to properties are restricted.  I don't think you can achieve this with AdminMessage.

Comment: @gamesmad The properties are protected so they can be accessed by inheriting classes. It doesn't matter anyway though because this is posting to a message queue. You can only add recipients, you cannot remove ones you haven't added.
Why don't you just remove those e-mail addresses through the admin console?

Comment: The accounts with permissions (other service accounts) in the admin console need them, they cannot be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not that familiar with the API in question. I might have missed something.

Having just rolled around in the code for a while I can see no way of doing this but that does not mean that there is no way.

The problem as far as I can tell is thus:

```
final class AdminMessage extends BaseMessage
```

That means that you can't extend AdminMessage which really just adds a lot of checks before

```
ApiProxy::makeSyncCall(
      'mail', 'SendToAdmins', $this->message, $response);
```

The class in question is not looping through the admins but simply triggering an API call to mail them all.

So this is, I think, an API issue rather than a code issue. If the API allows you to flag admins as not to be mailed then you can do what you are trying to do. Otherwise you might want to do something about the fact that you have two admins without active addresses.

If I were in your shoes I would consider what the best way would be to handle the bounces as elegantly as possible. You know that they are coming so what do you do with them?

To be honest almost everything to do with emailing encounters bounces but unless you have a stop list you can add the bounces to you just have got to go ahead and process them each time.

### References

- https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/AdminMessage.php?r=356
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/c10d3bdc6af30cb71cfb8a5a8551450e8ccce29c/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/BaseMessage.php